# how can i make alerts using js after inserting some data through php

Tags: php, javascript

I am inserting some information to my database and i am using the following pattern main page has a form. I send values entered in the form to **controller** and then insert it to **database** and back to my **main page** using **header(location:../etc)**.
What i want is that whenever i add some data in my **db** i want to show some **alert** that data has been added or anything to give feedback to user.
Can someone suggest me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Ajax? Learn about it. google _"ajax tuotrial"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ajax.  I suggest using jQuery because then you can just pass a callback function to the [get request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) which it will call when it gets the return.  For example:

```
 $.get("insertToDB.php", function(data){alert("Data Loaded: " + data);});
```

Comment: You can add callbacks to plain JS AJAX calls too, you know.

Comment: can you explain what this function is doing? i am assuming that when it hit backs to my main page from insertToDB.php (controller. in my case) it calls the function?

Comment: +1 jQuery is a great way to go, I would also suggest looking into the PHP native function called json_encode, which allows easy data manipulation on the javascript side.

Comment: @talhaMalik22 yes, it makes a get request to the php script named insertToDB.php, when this script returns it will call the javascript function shown here where the return of the php script goes into the javascript variable 'data'  and then gets alerted.

Comment: thanks a lot guys. i think i can do it now after some google. thanks a lot